# Формат времени в DateTimePicker не понимает tt

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

Попытка установить кастомный формат времени для `DateTimePicker` не дает нужного результата. [Документация по компоненту](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat(v=vs.110).aspx) говорит, что для показа `AM/PM` нужно добавлять в формат `tt`, но это ничего не дает. 
*Как уговорить эту фичу работать?*

[Скриншот фейла](https://yadi.sk/i/gEWlRINs3JgBc4)

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625136/5045688) пишут, что эта фича работает только в культуре, которая использует `AM/PM`. А `DateTimePicker` берёт значение культуры из региональных настроек ОС, задать ему провайдер вручную нельзя. Так что, в русскоязычной культуре - никак.

Comment: При большом желании можно взять [исходники](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs) этого класса, скопировать в свой проект, найти, где задаётся кастомный формат и изменить код.

Answer (score 0):

Формат  **DateTimePicker** ставьте вот так!

```
 dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
 dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "tt";
```

Напишите это в конструктор формы.

Comment: Это работатет **только** в культуре, где применяется обозначение дневного/ночного времени, например, в английской. `DataTimePicker` берёт значение культуры из региональных настроек ОС. Если у пользователя стоит, например, русскоязычная культура, то `tt` не работает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в чем проблема вот так тоже нормально работает или я что то не так понял?  
`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =  new CultureInfo("ru-ru")`  
  
 `dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;`  
 
    
`dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "tt";`

Comment: У вас англоязычная Винда? Поэтому и работает. `DateTimePicker` **не** учитывает культуру потока/приложения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда какой имеет смысл менять культрур если от этого ни какой пользы?В програме дальнейшем использовании показывает что культура  русская,но какая то часть программы не исползует её.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что это баг в `DateTimePicker`.